# Home Movie Media Sharing

Tags: video, media-player, archiving, media-manager

I want to provide a home movie video archive to several households to view on their TV.

**Question:** How can I share these to any smart TV: media server software, Google Drive, etc.?

The 35GB archive is 40 hours of video split across 25 video files.

Years back, the solution was simple. Duplicate the video tapes, later DVDs, and send to each family. They all had a VCR or DVD player. Now that families stream most video, perhaps a software solution could work.

1. First, I tried Google drive. This required connecting a laptop to the TV via HDMI and navigating video from the Google Drive website. Setting this up each time is a pain. Each home is limited by cable length, location of HDMI ports, etc.
2. Second, I tried just providing each household with a USB drive. This was a little better in they could view anywhere, but each Smart TV seems to have its own unique, poorly designed USB interface.
3. I considered a tiny media server PC in each home, software TBD.  This solution feels like overkill for sharing only 25 video files.
4. I considered hosting videos from my home. However, I am not sure how their SmartTV apps would connect to this server over the internet. I am unsure which software would be best here.